# Prove that if $\vec{x} \in \operatorname{Null}(A^TA)$ then $\vec{x} \in \operatorname{Null}(A).$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

How would you prove that if $\vec{x} \in \operatorname{Null}(A^TA)$ then $\vec{x} \in \operatorname{Null}(A)?$ I have been reading some proofs and am having trouble at a certain step specifically how $(Ax)^T(Ax)=\vec{0}\,$ implies that $Ax=\vec{0}.$

Comment: Assuming that $A$ is a real matrix, your step holds because $(Ax)^T (A x)$ is the square of the Euclidean norm of $Ax$. That is, if $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then $y^T y = y_1^2 + \cdots + y_n^2= ||y||^2$.

Comment: @MarkWildon I am not familiair with what you are explaining to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is a real $n \times p$ matrix and $x \in \mathbb{R} ^ p$, then 
$$
Ax=b_{n\times 1},
$$
i.e., $b$ is a vector from $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, note that 
$$
(Ax)^T Ax = b^Tb=(b_1,...,b_n) 
\begin{pmatrix}
b_1\\
\vdots \\
b_n
\end{pmatrix}
=b_1^2+b_2^2+\cdots b_n^2 \ge0,
$$
hence if $(Ax)^T(Ax) = b^Tb =0$ then every $b_i = 0$ for all $i=1,..,n$.